# Cantor's theorem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $A$ is a infinite set then the power set of $A$, $\mathcal{P}(A)$, is an uncountable set.

To proof first I take $A$ countable, and I suppose $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is countable, i.e., $\mathcal{P}(A)=\lbrace B_{0}, B_{1}, \cdots, B_{i}, \cdots \rbrace$, where $B_{i} \subset A$ is countable, than $B_{i}=\lbrace b_{i}^{0}, b_{i}^{1}, \cdots, b_{i}^{i}, \cdots \rbrace,  \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $B=\lbrace b_{0}, b_{1}, \cdots, b_{i}, \cdots \rbrace$, where $b_{i} \in A \smallsetminus B{i}$.

Since way was to $B \notin\mathcal{P}(A)$, but in the cases:

$B_{j}=A$ or $B_{j}=\emptyset$;

$B_{i}=A \smallsetminus \lbrace a_{i} \rbrace$, where $a_{i} \in A=\lbrace a_{0}, a_{1}, \cdots, a_{i}, \cdots \rbrace \Rightarrow A \smallsetminus B_{i}=\lbrace a_{i}\rbrace \Rightarrow b_{i}=a_{i} \Rightarrow B=A \in \mathcal{P}(A)$.

We have a failure.

How can I get around this so that, in this case, the first part of its demonstration is valid?

Comment: You may find my blog posting on the topic of infinity useful. See "Infinity, The Story So Far" (September 17, 2014) at https://www.dcproof.wordpress.com/ under the headings, "Cantor's Theorem" and "The Power Set of N is Uncountable."

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is **not** Cantor's theorem. Cantor's theorem says that if $X$ is a set, then $|X|<|\mathcal P(X)|$.

Now you can use this to show that if $|\mathcal P(X)|\leq\aleph_0$, then $|\mathcal P(X)|<\aleph_0$. Therefore, if $X$ was infinite, it has to be the case that $\mathcal P(X)$ is uncountable.